# A question on reciting the Veshamru

Tags: sources-mekorot, music, leil-shabbat, covenant

The Torah says:

> וְשָׁמְר֥וּ בְנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל אֶת־הַשַּׁבָּ֑ת לַעֲשׂ֧וֹת אֶת־הַשַּׁבָּ֛ת לְדֹרֹתָ֖ם בְּרִ֥ית עוֹלָֽם׃
> בֵּינִ֗י וּבֵין֙ בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֔ל א֥וֹת הִ֖וא לְעֹלָ֑ם כִּי־שֵׁ֣שֶׁת יָמִ֗ים עָשָׂ֤ה יְהוָה֙ אֶת־הַשָּׁמַ֣יִם וְאֶת־הָאָ֔רֶץ וּבַיּוֹם֙ הַשְּׁבִיעִ֔י שָׁבַ֖ת וַיִּנָּפַֽשׁ
> – Therefore the children of Israel shall keep the sabbath, to observe the sabbath throughout their generations, for a perpetual covenant.  It is a sign **between Me and the children of Israel** for ever; for in six days the Lord made heaven and earth, and on the seventh day He ceased from work and rested.’ [[Ex. 31:17](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.31.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)]

I remember hearing long ago that the phrase "beni uven bnei Israel – between Me and the children of Israel" must be recited or sung very fast, to reflect the fact that there is no daylight between us Jews and God.  (This is certainly done in the melodies I know.)  If such a teaching really does exist, does anybody have a source for it?

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bWBjR9n4i5HABb8_ez7yTk1zFs6H3oOh/view?usp=sharing) is the version we sang in Egypt, by yours truly (1988).

Comment: Most Ashkenazi melodies I know don't follow this teaching. It might be based on a kabbalistic teaching.

Comment: What does "there is no daylight between us Jews and God" mean?

Comment: It means that no one can come between us.

Answer (score 1):

I have not encountered melodies like this, but perhaps you could provide a link to such a melody or an audio recording, as compared with other melodies to demonstrate it.

Your comment elaborating the meaning of "there is no daylight between us Jews and God" was to the effect of "no one can come between us". This answer might not work with such an elaboration, but perhaps the source is the Zohar:

> ישראל אורייתא וקוב"ה כולא חד

Comment: This is the first return of a Google video search:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I75UNbqyk18  The second is the same tune:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMwZE7zQ0z4

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi It would be a nice thing to warn possibly sensitive users that these videos contain _kol ishah,_ especially during the _sefirah,_ because they also contain guitar as well.

Comment: Closer is אפילו מחיצה של ברזל אינה מפסקת בין ישראל לאביהם שבשמים, but both lack the "no daylight"

Comment: Hear the version in my edit.